# Are Pokemon training in a gym damaged?

Tags: pokemon-go

I couldn't find an existing question asking this, and the accepted [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/273703/125786) for **[How does training work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273689/how-does-training-work)** says:

> I don't *think* your returning Pokémon is buffed or damaged, but I can't say for certain

So, do you need to heal your Pokemon after training in a Gym, i.e. are they damaged? Do you need to revive them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, after training at a Pokégym, if your Pokémon takes any damage, they will need to be healed. Note, if your Pokémon loses, he will faint and need to be revived.

source: personal experience

Comment: Bingo. Stock up on potions before you hit the gym!

Answer (score 4):

Yes you do need to heal your pokemon after training in a Gym. The lowest they can go down is to 1 hp if it is your own team's gym while they can faint in an opposing faction's team which is when you need to use revive.
Personal experience.